# Convert data from `process.stdin` to upper-case data on `process.stdout` using the `through2` module.in nodeschool workshop of STREAM ADVENTURE

Tags: javascript

```
var through = require('through2');
var stream = through(write, end);

var tr =function write(buffer,encoding, next) {
    this.push(buffer.toString().toUpperCase()); 
    next();
}
process.stdin.pipe(through(tr)).pipe(process.stdout);
```

I am getting error

```
var stream = through(write, end);
                     ^
```

> ReferenceError: write is not defined
>       at Object. (C:\Users\GOTHAMI\stream\transform.js:2:22)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
>       at startup (node.js:134:18)
>       at node.js:962:3

Comment: It is exactly what it says, looks like thevariable `write` is not defined.

Comment: Move that line after the function definition.

Comment: function end (done) {
     done();
 }
after process statement i have one more function end.

Comment: stream must have two functions write and end that are combined using through

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this line;

`var stream = through(write, end);`